# The first time running my jsp page it gives a blank page and a null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsp, caching, cookies, nullpointerexception

It only Happens the first time i run my page or restart the glassfish server, i can even close the page and open it again and it wont show the exception and blank page until i restart the glassfish and run it again. The log shows some lines but those lines have no code so i dont really know whats the problem since i already check an i dont have any null variables.
here the log (let me know if you need the code):
Edit: I dont really understand why im getting downvoted, i tried to be ass clear as possible and gave the log with code.

```
Warning:   Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.Header_jsp._jspService(Header_jsp.java:57)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:977)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:48)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.Header_jsp._jspService(Header_jsp.java:57)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:977)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:48)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here the code that apparently is giving the exception:

```
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import="com.crimsonlogic.actors.SgcBean"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="com.crimsonlogic.databaseBeans.Login"%>
<%
    SgcBean.counterdeH++;
    HttpSession session2 = request.getSession();
    Cookie[] g = request.getCookies();
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("tipo", "");
    Cookie cuser = null;
    if (g.length > 0) {
        for (Cookie c : g) {
            System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + c.getValue());
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.getName().compareTo("tipo") == 0) {
                    cookie.setValue(c.getValue());
                }
                if (c.getName().compareTo("usuario") == 0) {
                    cuser = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ((cookie.getValue().compareTo("") == 0 || SgcBean.counterdeH < 2)) {
        session2.setAttribute("tipo", "U");
        cookie.setValue("U");
        System.out.println("Se esta ejecutando porque es null");
    } else {
        session2.setAttribute("tipo", cookie.getValue().substring(0, 1).toString());
        System.out.println("Se esta imprimiendo porque no es null " + cookie.getValue().substring(0, 1).toString());
    }

%>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>VUDA</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
        <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
        <!-- Themify Icons-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themify-icons.css">
        <!-- Magnific Popup -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"> 
        <!-- Owl Carousel  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
        <!--Gritter-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
        <!-- Theme style  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!--Obras css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/obras.css">
        <!--modal-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modalDelete.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto/Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <!--bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- tabs-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vtimbuc.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/dist/css/bootstrap-responsive-tabs.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vtimbuc.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/dist/js/jquery.bootstrap-responsive-tabs.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Modernizr JS -->
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
        <!--<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>-->


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="gtco-loader"></div>



        <div id="page">
            <div class="page-inner">

                <nav class="gtco-nav" role="navigation">
                    <div class="gtco-container">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <div id="gtco-logo"><a href="index.jsp">VUDA </a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8 text-right menu-1">
                                <ul> 
                                    <% if(session2.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("U")|| cookie.getValue().substring(0,1).contains("U")){ %>
                                         <li><a href="ObrasServlet?page=1">Obras</a></li>
                                         <li class="has-dropdown">
                                        <a href="paquetes.jsp">Paquetes</a>
                                        <%if(Login.idTitular != null){%>
                                        <ul class="gtco-dropdown">
                                            <li><a href="PaquetesActivos.jsp">Paquete Activo</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <%}%>
                                    </li>
                                         <% }else if(session2.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("T") || cookie.getValue().substring(0,1).contains("T")){%>
                                         <li><a href="ListaObrasServlet?page=1">Obras</a></li>
                                    <% }else if(session2.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("S") || cookie.getValue().substring(0,1).contains("S")){
                                        System.out.println("Se crearon los links");
                                    %>
                                         <li><a href="ListaTitularServlet?page=1">Titulares</a></li>
                                         <li><a href="ObrasServlet?page=1">Obras</a></li>
                                    <%}%>
                                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                                        <a href="#">Sedes</a>
                                        <ul class="gtco-dropdown">
                                            <li><a href="#">SGC</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Indecopi</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Ministerio de cultura</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">MCET</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <% if(session2.getAttribute("tipo").toString().contains("U") || cookie.getValue().substring(0,1).contains("U")){
                                          System.out.println(cookie.getName() + " " + cookie.getValue());
                                    %>
                                    <li><a href="#">PreCalculador</a></li>
                                    <% } %>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contactenos</a></li>
                                      <li  class="btn-cta" <% if(session2.getAttribute("username")!=null || cuser != null) out.print("style='display:none;'");%>><a id="btn2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span>Usuario</span></a></li>
                                    <li  class="btn-cta" <% if(session2.getAttribute("username")!=null || cuser != null) out.print("style='display:inline;'");else out.print("style='display:none;'");%>><a href="logoutServlet"><span>Cerrar Sesion</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </nav>


                <div class="container" <% if(session2.getAttribute("username")!=null || cuser != null) out.print("style='display:none;'");%>>
                <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog " id="loginModalDialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Iniciar Sesion</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-1 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
                                                <div class="form-wrap">
                                                    <form action="#">
                                                        <div class="row form-group">

                                                            <div class="col-md-12">   
                                                                <div for="username">Nombre de Usuario o Email</div>
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-12 right">
                                                            <a href="Registrarse.jsp">Registrarse</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">      
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form> 
                                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Here is the code, right. @Turing85

Comment: Yet another great example of why we *don't put Java code in a JSP*: The line numbers are meaningless. If the Java code had been in a .java file (Servlet), then you'd know exactly what line caused the error.

Comment: Javadoc of [`getCookies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()): *Returns an array of all the `Cookies` included with this request, or **`null` if the request has no cookies***. NPE is likely from `if (g.length > 0)`

Comment: `c.getName()` followed by `if (c != null)`? Is this for real? Why would you even check if `c` is null? `g` can be null, not `c`.

Comment: I have to eliminate this question... My god.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first check if `c` is null or not,then execute `System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + c.getValue());`

So change your code to below:

```
    for (Cookie c : g) {
        if (c != null) {
            System.out.println(c.getName() + " " + c.getValue());
            if (c.getName().compareTo("tipo") == 0) {
                cookie.setValue(c.getValue());
            }
            if (c.getName().compareTo("usuario") == 0) {
                cuser = c;
            }
        }
    }
```